# Filtering categories by some class name

Tags: jquery, css

I am having trouble filtering some list elements give an specific class
I have four categories at the top right of my website namely,
CMS, Programming, Design, All Projects

Given

```
 <div class = "container">
                <h1 id = "heading">All Projects</h1>
                <ul id = "gallery">

                    <li class = "design"><a href = "#"><img src = "img/web1.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li class = "design programming"><a href = "#"><img src = "img/web2.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li class = "cms"><a href = "#"><img src = "img/web3.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li class = "cms design"><a href = "#"><img src = "img/web4.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li class = "programming"><a href = "#"><img src = "img/web5.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li class = "design"><a href = "#"><img src = "img/web6.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li class = "design"><a href = "#"><img src = "img/web10.jpg"></a></li>
                    <li class = "cms design"><a href = "#"><img src = "img/web11.jpg"></a></li>

                </ul>
```

I am filtering them by doing

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('nav a').on('click',function(){

        //current class assignment
        $('nav li.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        //set Heading text

        $('h1#heading').text($(this).text());

        // get and filter text

        var category = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

        //remove hidden class if 'all-projects' is selected

        if(category == "all-projects"){
            $('ul#gallery li:hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        } else{

            $('ul#gallery li').each(function(){

                if(!$(this).hasClass(category))
                    {
                        $(this).hide().addClass('hidden');
                    }
                else{
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                }

            });
        }
        //stop link from behaviour
        return false;


    });
});
```

**My thoughts**

My initial plan was basically to loop through each of those classes and check whether or not regardless of an uppercase or hyphen they match up. I would give things that do not have the same class as the tag a hidden class, and obviously hide them. Where is my logic wrong?

After lots of testing I also realized its hiding every class. Not sure why this happens even though im testing it with a filter.

Comment: I think .replace(' ', '-') is the issue..

Comment: Ah. The issue was the extra spaces before Design, Programming and CMS. In <li><a href = "#"> CMS</a></li

Comment: I wonder. How can I get the program to ignore the blank spaces before?

Comment: that is a new question. + you should add 'with jQuery' to your title.